aws kafka get-bootstrap-brokers cli command returns nothin
I am running following command.
It executes without any error but returns nothing.
What can be the reason?
aws kafka get-bootstrap-brokers --cluster-arn  --region eu-central-1 --output json
I am expecting a list of brokers as outcome

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I realized that I installed the software with an other user so the problems seems to be permissions issue
